# How to make an import shortcut/alias in create-react-app?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, alias, create-react-app

How to set import shortcuts/aliases in create-react-app?
From this:

```
import { Layout } from '../../Components/Layout'
```

to this:

```
import { Layout } from '@Components/Layout'
```

I have a `webpack` 4.42.0 version.
I don't have a webpack.config.js file in the root directory. I've tried to create one myself with this code inside:

```
const path = require('path')

module.exports = {
  resolve: {
    alias: {
      '@': path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/'),
    }
  }
};
```

But it doesn't seem to work. I've seen the `NODE_PATH=.` variant in `.env` file. But I believe, it is deprecated - better not to use. And also, I have a `posstcss.config.js` file. Because I've installed the TailwindCss and I import the CSS library there. I've tried to paste the same code there, but it also didn't work.

Answer (score 45, accepted):

```
// Absolute path: paths which are relative to a specific path
import Input from 'components' // src/components
import UsersUtils from 'page/users/utils' // src/page/users/utils

// Alias path: other naming to specific path
import Input from '@components' // src/components
import UsersUtils from '@userUtils' // src/page/users/utils
```

In order for webpack's **aliases** to work, you need to configure the default `webpack.config.js` of `create-react-app`.

The **official way** is [to use the `eject` script](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/alternatives-to-ejecting).
But the **recommended way** is to use a library without ejecting (find the most modern library for that).

#### VSCode IntelliSense

In addition, you should add `jsconfig.json` file for path IntelliSense in VSCode (or `tsconfig.json`), [see followup question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58249053/how-to-intellisense-alias-module-path-in-vscode).

Now such code with IntelliSense will work:

```
// NOTE THAT THOSE ARE ALIASES, NOT ABSOLUTE PATHS
// AutoComplete and redirection works
import {ColorBox} from '@atoms';
import {RECOIL_STATE} from '@state';
```

Comment: Does this still apply today?  I tried putting Game.js in `src/components`, then using `import Game from 'components/Game'; - it didn't work.  Gave me the error saying `Requests that should resolve in the current directory need to start with './'.
Requests that start with a name are treated as module requests and resolve within module directories...` - perhaps this behaviour has changed.

Answer (score 74):

It is finally possible with Create React App v.3

Just put:

```json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": "src"
  },
  "include": ["src"]
}
```

into `jsconfig.json` or `tsconfig.json` if you use Typescript

Here is wonderful [article](https://medium.com/hackernoon/absolute-imports-with-create-react-app-4c6cfb66c35d) about this.

Comment: You always could make absolute imports via `jsconfig.json`, the question is about making *aliases*

Comment: @DennisVash the question _isn't_ about import aliases, it is about _import path shortcuts_, which this answer properly addresses. The fact that aliases are one of the multiple ways to reduce import paths length doesn't invalidate this answer.

Comment: Works but I think it's flawed. It could conflict with package names and does not make it clear that the imports are relative to the src folder in the sourcecode.

Answer (score 56):

Simplest way to archive this follow below steps. (same way as [@DennisVash](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63068531/7882470) showed as but in simple form)

1. Installation - install and setup CRACO.

```
yarn add @craco/craco

# OR

npm install @craco/craco --save
```

2. Create a `craco.config.js` file in the root directory and configure CRACO:

```
/* craco.config.js */
const path = require(`path`);

module.exports = {
  webpack: {
    alias: {
      '@': path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/'),
      '@Components': path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/components'),
      '@So_on': path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/so_on'),
    }
  },
};
```

3. Update the existing calls to `react-scripts` in the scripts section of your `package.json` file to use the craco CLI:

```
/* package.json */

"scripts": {
   "start": "craco start",
   "build": "craco build",
   "test": "craco test"
}
```

#### Done! Setup is completed.

Now let's test it.

```
// Before
import Button from "./form/Button" 
import { Layout } from '../../Components/Layout'

// After
import Button from "@/form/Button"
import { Layout } from '@Components/Layout'
```

Documentation [Craco](https://github.com/gsoft-inc/craco/blob/master/packages/craco/README.md#installation)

Thank you. :)

Comment: works fine, but until `craco test` is run then it cant find the alias, do you know what can cause this?

Comment: @Basit refer to https://github.com/dilanx/craco/blob/master/recipes/add-webpack-alias-to-jest/craco.config.js

Comment: @craco/craco will only support till react-script v4.x.x. it doesn't supports the latest react-scripts v5.x.x

Comment: craco 7 looks like will have support for react-scripts v5.x.x, https://github.com/dilanx/craco/issues/454#issuecomment-1273699896

Answer (score -1):

If you want to use:

```
// this:
import MyUtilFn from 'utils/MyUtilFn';
// Instead of this:
import MyUtilFn from '../../../../utils/MyUtilFn';
```

use the node module plugin for resolving the urls `https://www.npmjs.com/package/babel-plugin-module-resolver`. By installing it and adding it to your webpack/babel.rc file.

Comment: The plugin has been archived.

Comment: @VictorPudeyev You should be aware that the source GitHub repo has been archived. This means, seriously, if you have any problem in the future you have NOWHERE to report and NO ONE will fix it for you.

Answer (score -3):

Step 1

```
yarn add --dev babel-plugin-module-resolver
```

add this plugin

Step 2

in `babel.config.js` file

```
ALIAS NAME    ALIAS PATH

@navigation   ./src/navigation
@components   ./src/components
@assets       ./assets

[
  "module-resolver",
  {
    root: ["./src"],
    alias: {
      "^~(.+)": "./src/\\1",
    },
    extensions: [
      ".ios.js",
      ".android.js",
      ".js",
      ".jsx",
      ".json",
      ".tsx",
      ".ts",
      ".native.js",
    ],
  },
];
```

Step 3

```
import example

import SomeComponent from '@components/SomeComponent.js';
```

Step 4
restart server

```
yarn start
```

Reference link: [How to use import aliases with React native and VSCode](https://mtateam.medium.com/how-to-use-import-aliases-with-react-native-and-vs-code-dadb246674c7)

Comment: The plugin has been archived.

Comment: nothing is archived check below link https://www.npmjs.com/package/babel-plugin-module-resolver

Comment: Yes, it's archived: https://github.com/tleunen/babel-plugin-module-resolver. This means it will not receive any bug-fix, resolving any possible problem a user might encounter when using it. So this is why I downvoted, not because I don't appreciate your good mind helping people. It's just because the solution itself is no longer future-proof.

Comment: So what's the alternative ?