# getting rid of relative path react (removing "../..")

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, import, create-react-app

I have downloaded a react project with the following package.json :

```
{
  "private": true,
  "main": "src/index.js",
  "dependencies": {
    "@material-ui/core": "4.10.0",
    "@material-ui/icons": "4.9.1",
    "classnames": "2.2.6",
    "history": "4.10.1",
    "moment": "2.26.0",
    "node-sass": "4.14.1",
    "nouislider": "14.5.0",
    "prop-types": "15.7.2",
    "react": "16.13.1",
    "react-datetime": "2.16.3",
    "react-dom": "16.13.1",
    "react-router-dom": "5.2.0",
    "react-scripts": "3.4.1",
    "react-slick": "0.26.1",
    "react-swipeable-views": "0.13.9"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/cli": "7.10.1",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties": "7.10.1",
    "@babel/preset-env": "7.10.1",
    "@babel/preset-react": "7.10.1",
    "eslint-config-prettier": "6.11.0",
    "eslint-plugin-prettier": "3.1.3",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "7.20.0",
    "gulp": "4.0.2",
    "gulp-append-prepend": "1.0.8",
    "prettier": "2.0.5"
  },
  "optionalDependencies": {
    "typescript": "3.9.3"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "NODE_PATH=src/ react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build && gulp licenses",
    "test": "react-scripts test --env=jsdom",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject",
    "lint:check": "eslint . --ext=js,jsx;  exit 0",
    "lint:fix": "eslint . --ext=js,jsx --fix;  exit 0",
    "install:clean": "rm -rf node_modules/ && rm -rf package-lock.json && npm install && npm start",
    "build-package-css": "node-sass src/assets/scss/material-kit-react.scss dist/material-kit-react.css",
    "build-package": "npm run build-package-css && babel src --out-dir dist",
    "compile-sass": "node-sass src/assets/scss/material-kit-react.scss src/assets/css/material-kit-react.css",
    "minify-sass": "node-sass src/assets/scss/material-kit-react.scss src/assets/css/material-kit-react.min.css --output-style compressed",
    "map-sass": "node-sass src/assets/scss/material-kit-react.scss src/assets/css/material-kit-react.css --source-map true"
  }
  
}
```

I dont know how the developer got rid of relative path in his code.
for example he imports modules like:`import Header from "components/Header/Header.js";` 
although if I try to the same , i should do it like:`import header from "../../../src/components/Header/header.js"`.

the link to the original github:
`https://github.com/creativetimofficial/material-kit-react/`

i have downloaded and installed this one , it works fine.
but when i try to copy some of the codes,it doesnt work.

Comment: I dont think the original developer used webpack.

Comment: use the part where he describe craco, https://stackoverflow.com/a/65746792/2932476

Comment: link to the original project:[link](https://github.com/creativetimofficial/material-kit-react)

Comment: look at  jsconfig.json file

Answer (score 5, accepted):

use the `jsconfig.json` to set absolute path instead of reletive , as described in [documentation](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/importing-a-component/#absolute-imports)

in the provided project he used

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": "src",
    "paths": {
      "*": ["src/*"]
    }
  }
}
```

so he could accees all files using a absolute path , in all folder and subfolders of the project like

```
import file from "component/file/file.js"
```

Answer (score 1):

In the root directory of your project, create a `jsconfig.json` file and save this;

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": "src"
  },
  "include": ["src"],
  "exclude": ["node_modules"]
}
```

If you are using eslint in your project, you'll need to add this in your `.eslintrc.js` file;

```
  ...
  settings: {
    'import/resolver': {
      node: {
        paths: ['src'],
      },
    },
  },
  ...
```

You should be able to import files by their absolute path now.