# Is there a way in npm to import a src folder as a module?

Tags: reactjs, npm, node-modules

I have a React project with a structure like this:

- src

  - Components

    - My_component_1
    - My_component_2
  - Images

    - image_1
    - image_2
  - Pages

    - page_1
    - page_2

I'd like to know if exists a way to register a folder as a component (e.g @Images or @Components for all images or components).
In this way, if I'm working on sub-component of page 1, I will not need to write:

```
import component from "../../Components/My_component_1
```

but

```
import {My_component_1} from '@Components'
```

and avoid to manage relative url and different URLs in different components.

Comment: Look into [jsconfig.json](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/jsconfig)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can configure your jsconfig.json like this:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": "src"
  },
  "include": ["src"]
}
```

and then you will be able to import component like this:

```
import Button from 'components/Button';
```

Copied from https://create-react-app.dev/docs/importing-a-component/

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to configure path aliases or shortcuts in your project. You can read more about it here: [How to make an import shortcut/alias in create-react-app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63067555/how-to-make-an-import-shortcut-alias-in-create-react-app).

There are also a few posts online on how to do that, for example on the [medium.com](https://medium.com/) or [dev.to](https://dev.to/) website.