# Typescrcript path alias cannot find images, styles and other file extensions

Tags: reactjs, typescript, visual-studio-code, create-react-app

I currently have some react typescript projects, each project uses path alias, but I'm facing a annoying issue that, when import with path alias, the autocomplete for files like `.png`, `.jpg`, `.scss` and many other isn't found on path autocomplete. (it works fine when imported, the problem is just the annoying not working autocomplete that forces me to check the folder to get the file name)

When I use use the relative path such as `import File from '../../../styles/...';` the autocomplete works fine. I'm not sure for exactly what I need to search with this error, I've tried, but with no success.

I'm using **vscode** with [Path Intellisense](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=christian-kohler.path-intellisense) extension, but since the issue happens on typescript path alias I don't believe it can mean anything.

Working:

[image]

Not working:

[image]

*Don't show anything, if I hit `ctrl+enter` it show several useless autocompletes, but not the file inside the folder*

tsconfig

```json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es2020",
    "lib": [
      "dom",
      "dom.iterable",
      "esnext"
    ],
    "allowJs": false,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "strict": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "module": "esnext",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "downlevelIteration": true,
    "noEmit": true,
    "jsx": "react",
    "baseUrl": "./src",
    "types": ["cypress"]
  },
  "include": [
    "src"
  ]
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to intellisense alias module path in VSCode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58249053/how-to-intellisense-alias-module-path-in-vscode)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have the same problem with CRA v4 and absolute imports. Only way I ended up working:

1. Install [Path Intellisense](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=christian-kohler.path-intellisense) + add `"baseUrl": "src"` to your `tsconfig.json`
2. DO NOT set `"typescript.suggest.paths": false` as suggest extension readme, let it as `true`
3. Add the following to your VSCode `settings.json`:

```
    "path-intellisense.mappings": {
        "/": "${workspaceFolder}",
        "assets": "${workspaceFolder}/src/assets",
        "pages": "${workspaceFolder}/src/pages",
        ... as many lines as folders you have under src, or order paths too
    }
```

Comment: Works well whithout step 3,now VSC see other file paths.Upvoted.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to define the `paths` configuration inside `tsconfig.json`?

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "paths": {
      "@assets/*": ["your/path/to/assets/*"]
    }
  }
}
```

and use it like:

```
import Image from '@assets/';
```

Read more about path aliases [here](https://dev.to/larswaechter/path-aliases-with-typescript-in-nodejs-4353)

Comment: I just tried and gone event worst, only the main path works, it don't retrieve neither the sub-folders.

Comment: How does this resolve a specific image(png) import?