# I don't understand why export like this in React

Tags: reactjs, typescript, import, export

I found many files were exported like this, but I don't understand why these were exported this way.
Are there any advantages or reasons?

index.ts

```
export { default } from './Something'
```

---

Something.tsx

```
cosnt _Something= () => {
 some codes....
}

cosnt Something = memo(_Something)

export default Something
```

These two tsx file exist same directory.

Answer (score 0):

You're looking for default [export and named exports](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/export).

in `export default Something` case, you can use it with `import Something from 'path'`. So you only want to export one thing. It can be used as a namespace also. It equals `export { myFunction as default };`

in `export { Something }` case, you can use it with `import { Something } from 'path'`. You can export many things with names. It increases the readability. For sure, you can also `import { Something as Another} from 'path'`.

These two appoarches are not conflict. But only one default can be assigned.

```
// index.ts
export default function Something(){
}
export const CONST_A = 'A'
export const CONST_B = 'B'

// use.ts
import { default as Something, CONST_A, CONST_B} from './index.ts'
```

Answer (score 0):

Its just a pattern, instead of importing exact paths:

```
import Nav from 'components/Nav.react';
import Tooltip from 'components/Tooltip.react';
```

Sometimes you want a merge:

```
import { Nav, Tooltip } from 'components';
```

It requires exports from `index` file located at the target folder ('components' in this case):

```
// src/components/index.ts

export * from './Nav.react';
export * from './Tooltip.react';

// Or
export { Nav } from './Nav.react'; // Has a named export
export { default as Tooltip } from './Tooltip.react'; // Has default export
```

See more context in other question [How to intellisense alias module path in VSCode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58249053/how-to-intellisense-alias-module-path-in-vscode).